# Is there a way to pretty format or beautify NSIS script source code?

Tags: formatting, format, nsis, code-formatting

I've got an NSIS script that is a couple thousand lines and not properly indented making the script difficult to read. Is there a way to format NSIS script or at the minimum be able to indent the Ifs and Endifs sections? There's plenty of online script formatters for HTML, Javascript, XML, etc.

Comment: As far as I know there is no such thing. makensis has no such option built in — in contrary: it removes all indentation when outputting the script to stdout.

Comment: Have you at least got syntax highlighting?

Answer (score 1):

[Notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/) does an excellent job of supporting the NSI code conventions straight out of the box.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I've used [EclipseNSIS](http://eclipsensis.sourceforge.net/index.shtml) for working with NSIS before; it at least uses syntax highlighting, which is nice.

[Atom Editor](https://atom.io/) is also really nice for NSIS, and it has some packages you can add on to make it easier to work on NSIS scripts.

I don't think I ever found anything to prettify or format the script, unfortunately, but that may now be a part of either Atom or EclipseNSIS, I'm not sure.